# Page redirection and referrer using Steam Authentication

Tags: php, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I am relatively new to programming and have become stuck. I am unsure of what to call this (and what to search to find the answer) so if it is a duplicate or the answer can be found easily please forgive me.

So on my site I give a referral URL to users which is something like

```
www.example.com/referral.php/?id=1234
```

My problem comes from when someone visits my site with that link.

Once they click the enter that link and come to my server. They are then prompted to login through [Steam](http://www.steamcommunity.com) servers and after that they are returned to my site with a URL which is something like this

```
www.example.com/referral.php?login&openid.ns=... it continues on for a while.
```

Is it possible to have them return to my site with this link?

```
www.example.com/referral.php/?id=1234
```

As it is what my site uses to register referrals.

Or is there some workaround possible such as I pull the id and put it on a cookie or something similiar on the first visit to the site.

Thanks for the help.